# How to use IIS redirect when one site is merging with another - Azure Webapp

Tags: redirect, web-config

I have an azure webapp where I just moved one IIS site to [previously this was a WordPress site]. Let's call this one site1.com and I have another site2.com pointing to this website as well (DNS). We purchased a redirect module from American Eagle [[How to Manage 301 Redirects in Sitefinity]](https://www.americaneagle.com/insights/blog/post/managing-301-redirects-in-sitefinity)
and this application handles page level redirects for both sites. For example, if a request comes in for [www.site2.com/site2blog/](http://www.site2.com/site2blog/), the application handles in the backend to redirect that to [www.site1.com/blog](http://www.site1.com/blog). Similar way, if a request comes in for [www.site1.com/oldurl](http://www.site1.com/oldurl), it should redirect to [www.site1.com/newurl](http://www.site1.com/newurl) as well.

My question is, in this case, what should I have in the web.config for my new site. This is what I have at present -

```
<rule name="Redirect site2 root to site1" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?site2\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.site1.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirects to non-www to www - site1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site1\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.site1.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

As of now, any requests for site2.com goes to the root of site1 - for example, [www.site2.com/site2blog/](http://www.site2.com/site2blog/) goes to [www.site1.com/](http://www.site1.com/) and all [www.site1.com/oldurl](http://www.site1.com/oldurl) setup throws a 404. How can I modify the web.config entries to make this work? Please post back if you have any questions.

Comment: If you've purchased a redirect module from AE, wouldn't that involve setting these rules in the backend of Sitefinity? Otherwise, if you want to set the rule in the web.config - you don't need to purchase any module for that, it's handled by the .net framework

Comment: Veselin, 

Yes, we have the redirect module from AE, but I thought that needed some basic settings in web.config. When I remove these from web.config, none of the old links (that I have setup in AE redirects at the backend) work. Since this is a third party application, I decided to post here instead of Sitefinity portal. Will Progress help me with anything?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly this redirect module that you purchased work, do you have link so i can read more?

Comment: https://www.americaneagle.com/insights/blog/post/managing-301-redirects-in-sitefinity - this is what they have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you should have a new Dynamic Module, that's probably not activated yet. Can you go to Administration > Modules and Services and see if you see the AE Redirect module and if it is enabled?
If so, then you should find it somewhere in the menu, e.g. under the Content menu. If not, you'll need to activate it.

If you are on multi-site edition, you may need to add that module to your current site by going to Manage Sites from the top left corner and then Configure Modules.

Comment: I see a "Redirects" module that is active. This application was working before, through the .azurewebsites.net site and stopped once I activated the custom domain .site1.com through Azure. That's why I thought the issue is with the web.config entries.

Comment: do you have any rules defined in the Redirects module?

Comment: I was compiling these redirects through web.config since AE redirect application doesn't work. On the redirect module, what we have is just what is the source URL and what's the target URL. It worked when the site was in *.azurewebsites.net domain and when I pointed the domain to the *.azurewebsites.net site, it stopped working. AE's documentation doesn't say much about adding anything in the rewrite section at all.

Comment: why not get some support from AE, given that you already paid for the module?

Comment: I wish they will respond. I sent them an email on the 15th and never got a reply. That's why I tried my luck here.

Thanks for trying to help me.